# Getting SelectedIndexChanged event of checkboxlist using javascript

Tags: javascript, selectedindexchanged

I have a checkboxlist control in one of the web application. I want to use javascript to handle the SelectedIndexChanged event.

The checkbox list is like

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Four</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Five</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

How can I get the SelectedIndexChanged event using javascript?

Answer (score 4):

On server side.. put the follwoing..

```
CheckBoxList1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ChangeCheckBox();");
```

In client side JavaScript section, implement the following function

```
function ChangeCheckBox() {}
```

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the checkbox list event with this.
Also there is a checkbox in my UI, so I am using the same onclick to get the checkbox event. But I am not getting this event when checkbox is selected. Should we use a different event for checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

```
  document.getElementById('CheckBoxList1').onchange = function () {
                var input = document.getElementById('CheckBoxList1').getElementsByTagName("input")
                for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                    if (input[i].type == "checkbox") {
                        if (input[i].checked == true) {
                            alert(input[i].value);//Get all the checked checkboxes
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```